# Merge XML documents together overwriting certain elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a 2 input xml files. A template xml file eg

```
<test>
  <a>0</a>
  <b>0</b>
  <c>0</c>
  <d>0</d>
  <e>0</e>
</test>
```

and a data xml file that specifies values overriding those in the template xml. The data xml file may not specify values for all elements in the template xml eg

```
<test>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
  <c>3</c>
</test>
```

or

```
<test>
  <e>5</e>
</test>
```

The final xml should be superimpostion of the data xml over the template xml. eg

```
<test>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
  <c>3</c>
  <d>0</d>
  <e>0</e>
</test>
```

or

```
<test>
  <a>0</a>
  <b>0</b>
  <c>0</c>
  <d>0</d>
  <e>5</e>
</test>
```

How can this be done with XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

For just one level of depth like you have there, this should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="replacementFile" select="'replacements.xml'" />
  <xsl:param name="replacements" select="document($replacementFile)" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:variable name="replacement" 
           select="$replacements/*/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$replacement | current()[not($replacement)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With your first XML snippet as the input document, and the second snippet saved as replacements.xml, the output is:

```
<test>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
  <c>3</c>
  <d>0</d>
  <e>0</e>
</test>
```

If the replacements are not stored in a file, you can instead pass in the replacements XML document as a parameter value with the name `replacements`.  The above XSLT would remain the same. Alternatively, if the values *are* in a file, but different files might be used at different times, you can instead pass in the file path as a parameter with the name `replacementFile`.  Again, the above XSLT would need no modification to do that.

Comment: Is a generic solution possible for XML that is more than 1 level deep?

Comment: Yes, but surely with some limitations (such as not allowing siblings with the same name).  Could you provide an example of some multi-level XML that you would want to merge?

Comment: Actually the pairs of XML documents to merge are varied and depending on the document some elements may repeat at different levels. I was wondering if it would be possible to use an xpath value instead of local-name to do the inter-document matching. Secondly which would make a better implementation, XSLT or a dedicated program?